# Prove that the union of relations is an equivalence relation

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Let $\{\alpha_i \mid i\in \mathbb N\}$ is family of equivalence relations on the set $A$ such that for every $i \in N$ $\alpha_i\subseteq\alpha_{i+1}$. Prove that the union of all $\alpha_i$ is equivalence relation on $A$.

Whenever there are problems involving family of relations I'm clueless. I know that we obviously need to prove reflexivity,symmetry and transitivity but other than that I can't even begin.

Comment: I guess you forgot to mention that all the $\alpha_i$ are equivalence relations. (Otherwise there are trivial counterexamples.)

Comment: I also thought that they are supposed to be. But nowhere in the question it is stated that they are also equivalence relations.That's why I was mostly clueless about how to begin(It's an old exam question).

Comment: Well, that must be a mistake. Before looking at my hint: Can you proof this assuming that all the $\alpha_i$ are equivalence relations?

Comment: I also fixed the formatting of your post. For the future, [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial.

Comment: I would perhaps be able to prove some of it. But the whole idea of family of sets/relations is a bit confusing to me (mainly cause I haven't encountered it much)

Comment: @StefanMesken.  While you were at it, why didn't you fix the error in the problem statement?

Comment: @WilliamElliot Because my policy, when it comes to edits of foreign posts, is to not change the meaning of any post. I'll leave that to OP.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Note also that in this case, there are several viable ways to correct the exercise OP stated. For example it suffices for the $\alpha_i$ to be equivalence relations on a subset of $A$ such that $\operatorname{dom} \left( \bigcup_{i \in \mathbb N} \alpha_i \right)  = A$. Even weaker requirements still imply that their union is an equivalence relation. So, as far as I'm concerned, there is no clearly 'correct' edit unless OP provides more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof is really straightforward and one of those 'let use make sure you understand the definition' kind of exercises. I'll get you started and then you'll pick it up from there:

Let's proof that $\alpha := \bigcup \{ \alpha_i \mid i \in \mathbb N \}$ is transitive - reflexivity and symmetry are even easier:

Let $x,y,z \in A$ such that $(x,y) \in \alpha$ and $(y,z) \in \alpha$. Then there are, by the definition of $\alpha$, $i,j \in \mathbb N$ such that $(x,y) \in \alpha_{i}$ and $(y,z) \in \alpha_j$. Let $k = \max\{i,j\}$. Then $\alpha_i, \alpha_j \subseteq \alpha_k \subseteq \alpha$ and thus $(x,y),(y,z) \in \alpha_k$.

Now we use the fact that $\alpha_k$ is an equivalence relation to conclue that $(x,z) \in \alpha_k$. Since $\alpha_k \subseteq \alpha$, it follows that $(x,z) \in \alpha$ and thus that $\alpha$ is transitive.